# F# Common infix operators (fmap, applicative, bind, etc) for multiple types

Tags: .net, f#, infix-notation, infix-operator

What I would like do is use infix fmap (which I have defined as <^>) to work for multiple types such as Option and Either (custom type).

Given:

```
   type Either<'a, 'b> = Left of 'a | Right of 'b
```

In code I would like to be able to do:

```
   let fO (a : int option) = None
   let fE (a : Either<string,int>) = Left "dummy"

   let mO = Some 1
   let mE = Right 1

   let testO = f0 <^> m0
   let testE = fE <^> mE
```

Where (<^>) for each:

```
    let (<^>) f m = match m with | Some a -> Some <| f a | None -> None
    let (<^>) f m = match m with | Right a -> Right <| f a | Left a -> Left a
```

To get the Option <^> to work I have extended the module :

```
    namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Core
    [<AutoOpen>]
    module Option =
    let (<^>) f m = match m with | Some a -> Some <| f a | None -> None

    [<assembly:AutoOpen("Microsoft.FSharp.Core")>]
    do ()
```

And for Either:

```
    type Either<'a, 'b> = Left of 'a | Right of 'b with
       static member (<^>) (f,m) = match m with | Right a -> Right <| f a | Left a -> Left a
```

This almost works, however only one can be used at a time.
An Either module can be also appended to FSharp.Core, but then equally you can only have one or the other.

I'm aware this can be completed with 2 custom types, say Either and Maybe (Haskell option), I would however like to stick with Option.

Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: I don't have enough experience to answer your main question, but are you aware of F#'s [`Choice` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.choice%5B't1,'t2%5D-union-%5Bfsharp%5D)? It's the built-in equivalent to `Either`. Or if Left represents a "failure" case and Right represents a "success" case, then the F# equivalent is the [`Result` type](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1004-result-type.md), available since F# 4.1.

Comment: You might want to have a look to [F#+](https://github.com/gusty/FSharpPlus) which already does this, although the operator for ``fmap`` is ``<<|`` (same operator is used in FParsec). You have also ``bind`` as ``>>=`` and the applicatives ``<!>`` and ``<*>``. If you look at the source code you'll see how it's implemented, it's a refinement of the technique explained in the answer below by @TheInnerLight

Comment: @Gustavo Good point, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't really something that's easy to represent in F#, the only way to do this is using statically resolved type parameters and it's generally not considered idiomatic.

Doing this is quite easy for new, custom types but retrofitting it into existing types is more complex.  Supporting both is slightly harder again.

The way you can proceed is to create a helper type of a single case discriminated union with static methods hard-coded for existing types:

```
type Functor = Functor
    with 
    static member FMap (Functor, mapper : 'T -> 'U, opt : Option<'T>) : Option<'U> =
        Option.map mapper opt
    static member FMap (Functor, mapper : 'T -> 'U, ch : Choice<'T, _>) : Choice<'U, _> =
        match ch with
        |Choice1Of2 v -> Choice1Of2 (mapper v)
        |Choice2Of2 v -> Choice2Of2 v
```

Now you can use a function with statically resolved type paramters to choose the appropriate method based on type:

```
let inline fmap (f : ^c -> ^d ) (x : ^a) =
    ((^b or ^a) : (static member FMap : ^b * ( ^c -> ^d ) * ^a -> ^e ) (Functor, f, x))
```

Notice the `^b or ^a` condition?  That also gives us a method to insert this behaviour into custom types.

```
type Either<'a, 'b> = Left of 'a | Right of 'b with
    static member FMap (Functor, f, m) = 
        match m with | Right a -> Right <| f a | Left a -> Left a
```

For operator form, just define:

```
let inline (<^>) f x = fmap f x
```

You end up with functions defined:

```
val inline fmap :
  f:( ^c ->  ^d) -> x: ^a ->  ^e
    when (Functor or  ^a) : (static member FMap : Functor * ( ^c ->  ^d) *  ^a ->  ^e)
val inline ( <^> ) :
  f:( ^a ->  ^b) -> x: ^c ->  ^d
    when (Functor or  ^c) : (static member FMap : Functor * ( ^a ->  ^b) *  ^c ->  ^d)
```

Now you can do this type of thing with the `<^>` operator:

```
let x  = (fun x -> x + 1) <^> (Some 1)
let x'  = (fun x -> x + 1) <^> (None)
let z<'a> : Either<'a, _> = (fun x -> x + 2) <^> (Right 2)
let z'  = (fun x -> x + 2) <^> (Left 5)
```

---

Also you can take a look at [F#+](https://github.com/gusty/FSharpPlus) for a more complete implentation of many of these standard functional abstractions.

Comment: Thx, has really helped, I'm trying to expand this idea out to applicative and it isn't quite working. How would I define                                                                            `let inline fmap (f : ^c -> ^d ) (x : ^a) =
        ((^b or ^a) : (static member FMap : ^b * ( ^c -> ^d ) * ^a -> ^e ) (Functor, f, x))` for the applicative? not sure how to compose `f : ^c -> ^d` to cope with functions in context (Option, Either).

Comment: My implementation seems to works using Option and Choice but not Either.

Comment: @rbonallo Hard to supply a working implementation in a comment but the custom `Either` implementation should look like this for apply: `static member Apply (Applicative, fa, x) = match fa with | Right f -> Either<_, _>.FMap(Functor, f, x) | Left e -> Left e`

Comment: Why do you have to pass the Functor type to your FMap Implementation. Does this have something to do with resolving the inline method constraint?

Comment: @ThomasDevries Yep, we're just exploiting the `^a or ^b` syntax and allowing `^b` to be constrained to be of type `Functor` so we resolve against the correct type.

Comment: Thanks for this. After trying this code, I get a warning at `Functor` in the `fmap` definition: _warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'b has been constrained to be type 'Functor'._ Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, eventual implementation

```
type Functor = Functor
    with 
    static member FMap (Functor, mapper : 'T -> 'U, opt : Option<'T>) : Option<'U> =
        Option.map mapper opt
    static member FMap (Functor, mapper : 'T -> 'U, ch : Choice<'T, _>) : Choice<'U, _> =
        match ch with
        |Choice1Of2 v -> Choice1Of2 (mapper v)
        |Choice2Of2 v -> Choice2Of2 v

type Applicative = Applicative
    with 
    static member Apply (Applicative, mapperInContext : Option<('T -> 'U)>, opt : Option<'T>) : Option<'U> =
        match mapperInContext with | Some mapper -> Option.map mapper opt | _ -> None
    static member Apply (Applicative, mapperInContext : Choice<_,_>,  ch : Choice<'T,_>) : Choice<'U,_> =
        match mapperInContext with
        | Choice1Of2 mapper -> 
           match ch with
           |Choice1Of2 v -> Choice1Of2 (mapper v)
           |Choice2Of2 v -> Choice1Of2 v
        | Choice2Of2 v -> Choice2Of2 v

let inline fmap (f : ^c -> ^d ) (x : ^a) =
    ((^b or ^a) : (static member FMap : ^b * ( ^c -> ^d ) * ^a -> ^e ) (Functor, f, x))

let inline applicative (mf : ^f ) (x : ^a) =
    ((^b or ^a) : (static member Apply : ^b * ^f * ^a -> ^e ) (Applicative, mf, x))

let inline (<^>) f x = fmap f x

let inline (<*>) m x = applicative m x

type Either<'a, 'b> = Left of 'a | Right of 'b with
    static member FMap (Functor, f, m) = 
        match m with | Right a -> Right <| f a | Left a -> Left a

    static member Apply (Applicative, fa, x) = match fa with | Right f -> Either<_, _>.FMap(Functor, f, x) | Left e -> Left e
```